# DMX512 Remote controlled LED

Tags: microcontroller, led, rs485, receiver, transceiver

I'm having a problem with this circuit. I am trying to get an LED wash light circuit to be remote controlled via DMX512. The problem is, after I designed the circuit for the RS485 (which will deliver the DMX signal to my LED circuit) my professor told me that there's no time to make it and that I should just buy it. I couldn't find a descent one to buy. I am also not sure if I should connect the LEDs with parallels or using a darlington pair?
[image]

[image]

I have attached the circuitry for the RS485. Also, the options I have to connect the LEDs, not even sure which microcontroller is the best for them. Any help? It's also 5 - 9 LEDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to terminate RS485 at both ends. 54 to 100 ohm range.
[image]

To switch LEDs on, Choose the number of LEDs by forward voltage at rated current to add up like zener diodes and allow ~1V for current limiting resistor for fixed regulator (use 2V drop, if using battery, say 13V with +/-1V tolerance.

Vf of LED depends on colour and current.
LEDs must have a good heatsink.
You can choose any transistor that has enough current gain from logic level to LED.

Choose MOSFET or BJTs (Darlingtons is more current gain needed as single stage BJT gain is only 10~30x typ saturated.)

Alternatively use constant current sink which regulates well but less efficient than <1V Rs current limiter.

Typ >2V drop min. on MOSFET) If= 0.7/Rs
[image]

If fixed regulator, I would go with <1V drop power resistor for each string.

For more info on LEDs see my other links.
["low current", "high efficiency", "high intensity" LED's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49458/low-current-high-efficiency-high-intensity-leds/49473#49473)

[LED current limiting resistor and Ohm's Law](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49548/led-current-limiting-resistor-and-ohms-law/49573#49573)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother, but do you have any website that I can buy an RS485 from? because now I'm working on the LEDs circuit, and according to my dr. I don't need to build an RS485.

Comment: Sure Digikey ships same day on Visa  http://www.digikey.com/scripts/dksearch/dksus.dll?FV=fff40027%2Cfff801a4&k=485&vendor=0&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ptm=0&fid=0&quantity=0&PV578=54&PV578=58&PV578=56&PV578=32&PV578=33&stock=1